# read all the files from s3 bucket python sorted by time

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get all the files content sorted by the time the file was uploaded, I have this code:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my_bucket')['Contents']
[obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified)]
```

but it gives me only 1000 file though I got more in the bucket,
what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

`list_objects_v2` is limited to the first 1000 objects. API responses have a ContinuationToken field, which can be passed to the ListObjects API to get the next page of results. By looking for this token, and using it to make another request, we can steadily fetch every key in the bucket:

```
"""Get a list of all keys in an S3 bucket."""
keys = []

kwargs = {'Bucket': 'my_bucket'}
while True:
    resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
    for obj in resp['Contents']:
        keys.append(obj['Key'])

    try:
        kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
    except KeyError:
        break
```

More details https://alexwlchan.net/2017/07/listing-s3-keys/

Comment: using the function s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs) I cannot get the file content... what can I do?